# In Ruby on Rails view templates what does "<%_" and mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am familiar with:

```
<%= var  %>  # rails output
```

and

`<%- method %>`  # to execute ruby code without any output

Now I am also seeing view templates with

```
<%_ final_cost %>
```

What does the underscore mean?

Comment: Is it `<%- final_cost %>` ? or as you said? I meant no typo right ?

Comment: Do you have an example of where this is used to point to? I'm also wondering if perhaps `_` is the name of a method that's being called here?

Comment: my bad, turned out to be js not erb

Answer (score 1):

Turned out these are NOT erb templates - my mistake.  They are .html files.

and...

this code is for javascript - the underscore framework.

Comment: Should probably just delete the entire question then...

Comment: No keep -- it's a good way to see how this stuff works